# why cant I change my launcher icon size?

Tags: compiz, customization

When I set ubuntu as a dual boot I only had issues with unity crashing when using ccsm.Earlier I was trying to resize my launcher icons with ccsm and then with ubuntu tweak and both of them made unity crash with no bars.On a brighter note I do have the desktop cube,lol.Anyone have a workaround for this situation?I have switched to a better computer with different graphics card,both cards in each computer were both ati though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah 
press cntrl + alt + t to open the terminal ,and type

unity --reset

ccsm is very dangerous in unity,so dont play with it if it is not necessory :)

Comment: If it wont work press  alt+cntrl+f2
and type unity --reset
then press alt+cntrl+f7

Comment: O yeah I can get unity reset with no probs just tired of doing it,lol.I also found out that if I uncheck unity plugin before I check desktop cube and rotate cube then check unity plugin after I am done that I won't crash unity and have the cube operable.This time though I used at first ubuntu tweak to change launcher icon size and unity crashed,when I got my bars back I tried it with ccsm and also crashed.On my old computer changing icon size in launcher was a breeze so what gives here ?